# Python folder create and read text file

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a program but stuck with some steps. The aim of the program is find the folder names from the txt file which user inputs and create new files and files accordingly separated with '->' I developed a code to read the text file, split the list of the folder names in the list but can not create folders.
Code partially works but can not create files named from the list I spitted.

The txt file:

```
X
X -> Y
X -> Y -> Z
X -> Y -> Z.txt
X -> X.txt
X -> Y -> T
X -> Y -> T.txt
```

My output with the split list:

```
X
['X', '->', 'Y']
['X', '->', 'Y', '->', 'Z']
['X', '->', 'Y', '->', 'Z.txt']
['X', '->', 'X.txt']
['X', '->', 'Y', '->', 'T']
['X', '->', 'Y', '->', 'T.txt']
```

My Code:

```
import os
path = input("enter filepath: ")
word = '->'

with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            sp_line = line.split()
            for folder in path:
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, str(sp_line)))

        else:
            print(line)
```

Expected output:

```
Input file from directory X.txt
X folder named X
"C:\...\X\X.txt"
"C:\...\X\Y\Z\Z.txt"
"C:\...\X\Y\T\T.txt" And, txt files has to contain the directory string in them.
```

Comment: `for folder in path` loops through each letter of the **string** `path` and inside it you are creating a folder named `path/str(sp_line)` where sp_line is an array so it will loke something like this `path/['X', '->', 'Y']`. What is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fully understand what you want.

but, If I read your question in my own way,
You want to create folder or file from txt file.

Your input : txt file

```
X
X -> Y
X -> Y -> Z
X -> Y -> Z.txt
X -> X.txt
X -> Y -> T
X -> Y -> T.txt
```

Your output: create folder or file

```
mk directory: /.../X
mk directory: /.../X/Y
mk directory: /.../X/Y/Z
write file: /.../X/Y/Z.txt
write file: /.../X/X.txt
mk directory: /.../X/Y/T
write file: /.../X/Y/T.txt
```

In my code:

```py
import os


file = input("enter filepath: ")
# file = 'test.txt'

folder_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
split_word = '->'

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        sp_line = line.split(split_word)
        # print(sp_line)
        words = []
        for word in sp_line:
            word = word.strip()
            # print(word)
            words.append(word)
        # print(words)
        if '.' not in words[-1]:
            directory = os.path.join(*([folder_path] + words))
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                print('mk directory: {}'.format(directory))
                os.makedirs(directory)
        else:
            new_file = os.path.join(*([folder_path] + words))
            # if os.path.exists(new_file):
            #     print('write file')
            if not os.path.exists(new_file):
                with open(new_file, 'w'):
                    print('write file: {}'.format(new_file))
```

If you get an idea to solve your problem through this code, please modify it and use it.

Comment: Yes, exactly! in an addition I just want to write the directories to the txt files. Do you have any idea to make that?

Comment: I think, you should change your input file. for example, `X`, `X -> Y`, `X -> Y -> Z`, `X -> Y -> Z -> Z.txt` and you should write file only not directory.

Comment: Or, you can change input file just `X -> Y -> Z -> Z.txt`, `X -> X.txt`, `X -> Y -> T -> T.txt`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, this will work. I am accepting your answer too.